# Project Server 2010 installation on SharePoint Server 2010?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, project-server

We want to deploy Project Server 2010 on SharePoint Server 2010 farm? Should we need to buy the license of Project Server 2010 Even if we have the SharePoint 2010 Enterprise license.

Is it just the installation and running the configuration wizard?

Also, what is the difference between Project Web Access and Project professional 2010?

and does Project server 2013 a part of SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Please try to only ask one distinct question per post. Otherwise you are risking that not one single user knows the answer to all of your questions and hence do not answer at all.

Comment: Sure, I thought that all are relevant.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you will need one Project Server(PS) license for each SharePoint server that PS will be installed on. Also, you will need to buy a user license for each user that will have Project Server Professional installed on their desktop.

You will need to install the PS bits, run SP Configuration Wizard, provision a Project Server Service Application, configure your PWA settings.

Project Professional is the client version that runs on user's desktop. Project Web App (PWA) is the web version of Project which runs inside the browser.

Project Server 2013 is not part of SharePoint 2013, but it is install on top of SP.